# Selecting the stop criteria for Bisection Method

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, bisection

Q. Use the Bisection Method to find an approximation with accuracy $10^{-4}$ to the solution of  $x^3-x-1=0$  lying in the interval [1,2]

[image]

What should be the correct stopping criteria for this problem? 
If I choose $|b_n-a_n|$$<$Tolerence, the approximate value is 1.324707 (iter 11). If I decide $|P_n-P_{n-1}|/|P_n|$ $<$ Tolerance then I got approximate value
1.324829. I'm a little bit confused. Did I make any mistakes?
What criteria should I use to answer this question?

Similar solved problem..[image]

Comment: What makes you think you made a mistake ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust did my relative error calculation have any mistakes. is the answer correct?

Comment: The question doesn't say if the tolerance is absolute or relative nor to what you want to apply it.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes. you are correct. The question didn't mention it. So, can't we solve it?

Comment: Tell what you want.

Comment: Question didn't mention any stopping criteria. If so, what criteria should I select or most appropriate for this case?

Comment: Up to you, there is no rule.

Comment: Everything that you have been told above is wrong. You can readily check that $1.324707$ gives an error smaller than $10^4$, while $1.324829$ doesn't. You can check this by running the computation with even smaller tolerance to obtain a more precise solution.

Comment: In general bounding the relative error is useful for a general purpose algorithm such that it doesn't stop too soon for values close to zero, and to avoid unattainable stopping condition for large values. But this is when you are working blindly, a general purpose algorithm doesn't know for what specific problem it is going to be used. However, here you have a very concrete problem. Moreover, the solution is being sought in an interval in which the values have the same magnitude as $1$. This can explain why the stopping condition with the relative error is giving you a worse approximation.

Comment: @tora Plz. See I attached similarly solved problem. I also thought 1.324707 is correct. But according to this what you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ denote the unknown value which we seek to approximate. The most useful measure of the accuracy of an approximation $\hat{x}$, is the absolute error $$e = x - \hat{x}$$ and the relative error $$r = \frac{x - \hat{x}}{x}$$ which is only defined when $x \not = 0$.

Now, the phrasing of the original problem is weak and we cannot determine the author's intention with any certainty. However, the bisection algorithm affords us the opportunity to bound both the error and the relative error in terms of the brackets, i.e., the intervals $(a,b)$ which are produced.

Specifically, let $(a_j,b_j)$ denote the $j$th bracket and let $f$ denote our continuous function. We seek to solve $f(x) = 0$. We have different signs for $f(a_j)$ and $f(b_j)$. It follows that there exist a zero $x$ of $f$ in the interval $(a_j,b_j)$. Without additional information, the best approximation of $x$ is the midpoint $$x_j = \frac{a_j + b_j}{2}.$$ For the error we have
$$|e| = |x - x_j| \leq \frac{1}{2}|b_j - a_j|.$$
If $a_j$ and $b_j$ have the *same* sign, then $x = 0$ is impossible and the relative error $r$ is defined. In this case, we have the bound
$$|r| = \frac{|x-x_j|}{|x|} \leq \frac{\frac{1}{2}|b_j-a_j|}{\min\{|a_j|,|b_j|\}}.$$
Your objective should be to ensure that either
$$ \frac{1}{2}|b_j - a_j| \leq \tau $$
or 
$$ \frac{\frac{1}{2}|b_j-a_j|}{\min\{|a_j|,|b_j|\}} \leq \tau$$
where $\tau$ is the tolerance specified by the user.

Your own suggestion is to terminate the iteration when
$$ \left | \frac{x_j - x_{j-1}}{x_j} \right| \leq \tau$$
In general, this is not a bad choice, it simply that we can do better because the bisection method delivers more than just an approximation, it delivers an interval which contains the root.

---

If a choice must be made, then I would choose to bound the relative error. I would make this choice because I am using floating point arithmetic. Here, every number in the representational range can be approximated with a small *relative* error. In the absence of any additional information bounding the relative error is the "natural" choice.

Comment: Perfect...very clear. Thank you.